# NoClassDefFoundError with java-11

Tags: java

I am recently moved my code from java-8 to java-11. In one of my service i am facing NoClassDefFoundError

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Statement

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.Statement
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:718)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 18 more
```

Any suggestion....

Comment: You need to add `requires java.sql;` to your `module-info.java`

Comment: This will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52981800/getting-noclassfoundexception-java-sql-sqlexception-in-intellij-idea-for-jdk-1