# ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.SQLException while running Java 1.8 classes with Java 11

Tags: java, java-11, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to run a standalona Java 1.8 application -- that is working well with a JDK 1.8 -- with a Java 11 JVM by the command below

`"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java" --show-module-resolution --add-modules java.sql -jar runtime\scort\es\es_launchers.jar -PATH C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT -DEBUG`

and got this CNFE

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/SQLException
        at com.scort.es.persistentstorage.PersistentLocalObject.<clinit>(PersistentLocalObject.java:193)
        at com.scort.es.editor.terminals.repository.TerminalRepStorage.<clinit>(TerminalRepStorage.java:155)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
        at com.scort.es.project.EsProject.loadESPersistentResource(EsProject.java:261)
        at com.scort.es.project.EsProject.initDatabase(EsProject.java:228)
        at com.scort.es.project.EsProject.createNewPersistentStorageSession(EsProject.java:166)
        at com.scort.es.project.EsProject.createPersistentStorageSession(EsProject.java:130)
        at com.scort.es.editor.terminals.RepositoryManager.createTerminalStorage(RepositoryManager.java:117)
        at com.scort.es.editor.terminals.RepositoryManager.setTerminalInits(RepositoryManager.java:391)
        at com.scort.es.editor.terminals.RepositoryManager.setTerminalXML(RepositoryManager.java:357)
        at com.scort.es.editor.terminals.Editor.setup(Editor.java:512)
        at com.scort.es.editor.terminals.Editor.setDeskTop(Editor.java:214)
        at com.scort.es.framework.BeanManager.registerBean(BeanManager.java:483)
        at com.scort.es.framework.TabbedBeanViewer.addTab(TabbedBeanViewer.java:166)
        at com.scort.es.framework.TabbedBeanViewer.addBean(TabbedBeanViewer.java:132)
        at com.scort.es.framework.Framework$3$1.run(Framework.java:1808)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.SQLException
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at java.base/java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:899)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 33 more
```

The option `--show-module-resolution` displays in the log below the java.sql module.
Moreover I added the `--add-modules java.sql` also. So what could be the issue?

```
C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java" --show-module-resolution --add-modules java.sql -jar runtime\scort\es\es_launchers.jar -PATH C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT -DEBUG
root java.sql jrt:/java.sql
root java.rmi jrt:/java.rmi
root jdk.management.jfr jrt:/jdk.management.jfr
root jdk.jdi jrt:/jdk.jdi
root java.transaction.xa jrt:/java.transaction.xa
root java.logging jrt:/java.logging
root java.xml.crypto jrt:/java.xml.crypto
root jdk.xml.dom jrt:/jdk.xml.dom
root java.xml jrt:/java.xml
root jdk.jfr jrt:/jdk.jfr
root java.datatransfer jrt:/java.datatransfer
root jdk.httpserver jrt:/jdk.httpserver
root jdk.net jrt:/jdk.net
root java.naming jrt:/java.naming
root java.desktop jrt:/java.desktop
root java.prefs jrt:/java.prefs
root java.net.http jrt:/java.net.http
root jdk.compiler jrt:/jdk.compiler
root java.security.sasl jrt:/java.security.sasl
root jdk.jconsole jrt:/jdk.jconsole
root jdk.attach jrt:/jdk.attach
root java.base jrt:/java.base
root jdk.javadoc jrt:/jdk.javadoc
root jdk.jshell jrt:/jdk.jshell
root jdk.jsobject jrt:/jdk.jsobject
root jdk.sctp jrt:/jdk.sctp
root java.management jrt:/java.management
root java.sql.rowset jrt:/java.sql.rowset
root jdk.unsupported jrt:/jdk.unsupported
root java.smartcardio jrt:/java.smartcardio
root jdk.scripting.nashorn jrt:/jdk.scripting.nashorn
root java.instrument jrt:/java.instrument
root java.security.jgss jrt:/java.security.jgss
root jdk.management jrt:/jdk.management
root java.compiler jrt:/java.compiler
root jdk.security.auth jrt:/jdk.security.auth
root java.scripting jrt:/java.scripting
root jdk.dynalink jrt:/jdk.dynalink
root jdk.unsupported.desktop jrt:/jdk.unsupported.desktop
root jdk.accessibility jrt:/jdk.accessibility
root jdk.jartool jrt:/jdk.jartool
root java.management.rmi jrt:/java.management.rmi
root jdk.security.jgss jrt:/jdk.security.jgss
jdk.security.jgss requires java.security.jgss jrt:/java.security.jgss
jdk.security.jgss requires java.logging jrt:/java.logging
jdk.security.jgss requires java.security.sasl jrt:/java.security.sasl
java.management.rmi requires java.naming jrt:/java.naming
java.management.rmi requires java.management jrt:/java.management
java.management.rmi requires java.rmi jrt:/java.rmi
jdk.accessibility requires java.desktop jrt:/java.desktop
jdk.unsupported.desktop requires java.desktop jrt:/java.desktop
jdk.dynalink requires java.logging jrt:/java.logging
jdk.security.auth requires java.security.jgss jrt:/java.security.jgss
jdk.security.auth requires java.naming jrt:/java.naming
jdk.management requires java.management jrt:/java.management
java.security.jgss requires java.naming jrt:/java.naming
jdk.scripting.nashorn requires jdk.dynalink jrt:/jdk.dynalink
jdk.scripting.nashorn requires java.logging jrt:/java.logging
jdk.scripting.nashorn requires java.scripting jrt:/java.scripting
java.sql.rowset requires java.naming jrt:/java.naming
java.sql.rowset requires java.sql jrt:/java.sql
java.sql.rowset requires java.logging jrt:/java.logging
jdk.jsobject requires java.desktop jrt:/java.desktop
jdk.jshell requires jdk.jdi jrt:/jdk.jdi
jdk.jshell requires jdk.compiler jrt:/jdk.compiler
jdk.jshell requires java.prefs jrt:/java.prefs
jdk.jshell requires jdk.internal.opt jrt:/jdk.internal.opt
jdk.jshell requires jdk.internal.le jrt:/jdk.internal.le
jdk.jshell requires jdk.internal.ed jrt:/jdk.internal.ed
jdk.jshell requires java.compiler jrt:/java.compiler
jdk.jshell requires java.logging jrt:/java.logging
jdk.javadoc requires jdk.compiler jrt:/jdk.compiler
jdk.javadoc requires java.xml jrt:/java.xml
jdk.javadoc requires java.compiler jrt:/java.compiler
jdk.attach requires jdk.internal.jvmstat jrt:/jdk.internal.jvmstat
jdk.jconsole requires java.management jrt:/java.management
jdk.jconsole requires java.rmi jrt:/java.rmi
jdk.jconsole requires jdk.management jrt:/jdk.management
jdk.jconsole requires jdk.internal.jvmstat jrt:/jdk.internal.jvmstat
jdk.jconsole requires java.management.rmi jrt:/java.management.rmi
jdk.jconsole requires java.desktop jrt:/java.desktop
jdk.jconsole requires jdk.attach jrt:/jdk.attach
jdk.jconsole requires jdk.management.agent jrt:/jdk.management.agent
java.security.sasl requires java.logging jrt:/java.logging
jdk.compiler requires java.compiler jrt:/java.compiler
java.prefs requires java.xml jrt:/java.xml
java.desktop requires java.prefs jrt:/java.prefs
java.desktop requires java.datatransfer jrt:/java.datatransfer
java.desktop requires java.xml jrt:/java.xml
java.naming requires java.security.sasl jrt:/java.security.sasl
jdk.xml.dom requires java.xml jrt:/java.xml
java.xml.crypto requires java.logging jrt:/java.logging
java.xml.crypto requires java.xml jrt:/java.xml
jdk.jdi requires jdk.attach jrt:/jdk.attach
jdk.jdi requires jdk.jdwp.agent jrt:/jdk.jdwp.agent
jdk.management.jfr requires java.management jrt:/java.management
jdk.management.jfr requires jdk.management jrt:/jdk.management
jdk.management.jfr requires jdk.jfr jrt:/jdk.jfr
java.rmi requires java.logging jrt:/java.logging
java.sql requires java.transaction.xa jrt:/java.transaction.xa
java.sql requires java.logging jrt:/java.logging
java.sql requires java.xml jrt:/java.xml
jdk.management.agent requires java.management.rmi jrt:/java.management.rmi
jdk.management.agent requires java.management jrt:/java.management
java.datatransfer binds java.desktop jrt:/java.desktop
java.compiler binds jdk.javadoc jrt:/jdk.javadoc
java.compiler binds jdk.compiler jrt:/jdk.compiler
java.naming binds jdk.naming.dns jrt:/jdk.naming.dns
java.naming binds jdk.naming.rmi jrt:/jdk.naming.rmi
jdk.internal.jvmstat binds jdk.jstatd jrt:/jdk.jstatd
java.base binds jdk.charsets jrt:/jdk.charsets
java.base binds java.logging jrt:/java.logging
java.base binds java.management jrt:/java.management
java.base binds jdk.security.auth jrt:/jdk.security.auth
java.base binds java.desktop jrt:/java.desktop
java.base binds jdk.jdeps jrt:/jdk.jdeps
java.base binds jdk.jartool jrt:/jdk.jartool
java.base binds jdk.compiler jrt:/jdk.compiler
java.base binds jdk.javadoc jrt:/jdk.javadoc
java.base binds jdk.jlink jrt:/jdk.jlink
java.base binds jdk.localedata jrt:/jdk.localedata
java.base binds java.xml.crypto jrt:/java.xml.crypto
java.base binds jdk.security.jgss jrt:/jdk.security.jgss
java.base binds jdk.crypto.ec jrt:/jdk.crypto.ec
java.base binds java.security.sasl jrt:/java.security.sasl
java.base binds java.naming jrt:/java.naming
java.base binds java.smartcardio jrt:/java.smartcardio
java.base binds jdk.crypto.mscapi jrt:/jdk.crypto.mscapi
java.base binds jdk.crypto.cryptoki jrt:/jdk.crypto.cryptoki
java.base binds java.security.jgss jrt:/java.security.jgss
java.base binds jdk.zipfs jrt:/jdk.zipfs
java.desktop binds jdk.accessibility jrt:/jdk.accessibility
java.desktop binds jdk.unsupported.desktop jrt:/jdk.unsupported.desktop
jdk.jshell binds jdk.editpad jrt:/jdk.editpad
java.scripting binds jdk.scripting.nashorn jrt:/jdk.scripting.nashorn
java.management binds java.management.rmi jrt:/java.management.rmi
java.management binds jdk.management.jfr jrt:/jdk.management.jfr
java.management binds jdk.management jrt:/jdk.management
jdk.dynalink binds jdk.scripting.nashorn jrt:/jdk.scripting.nashorn
jdk.editpad requires jdk.internal.ed jrt:/jdk.internal.ed
jdk.editpad requires java.desktop jrt:/java.desktop
jdk.crypto.cryptoki requires jdk.crypto.ec jrt:/jdk.crypto.ec
jdk.jlink requires jdk.internal.opt jrt:/jdk.internal.opt
jdk.jlink requires jdk.jdeps jrt:/jdk.jdeps
jdk.jdeps requires jdk.compiler jrt:/jdk.compiler
jdk.jdeps requires java.compiler jrt:/java.compiler
jdk.jstatd requires jdk.internal.jvmstat jrt:/jdk.internal.jvmstat
jdk.jstatd requires java.rmi jrt:/java.rmi
jdk.naming.rmi requires java.naming jrt:/java.naming
jdk.naming.rmi requires java.rmi jrt:/java.rmi
jdk.naming.dns requires java.naming jrt:/java.naming
001.optional.PATH
        PATH    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\patch
002.optional.RECURSE(JAR)
300.PATH
        PATH    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\ini
400.RECURSE(JAR)
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\activation-1.1.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\ant-1.9.9.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\ant-launcher-1.9.9.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\jEdit-1.2.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\jempbox-1.8.16.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\JLex-1.2.6.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\jline-2.13.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\jmk-1.2.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\jora-1.0.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\jsr173-1.0.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\jsr173_api-1.0.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\jsyntaxpane-080717.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\jython-2.5.0.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\kawa-1.7.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\oro-2.0.8.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\pdfbox-1.8.16.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\picocontainer-2.15.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\reload4j-1.2.18.3.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\slf4j-api-1.7.35.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\slf4j-reload4j-1.7.35.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\stax-api-1.0-2.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\stax-api-1.0.1.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\swing-layout-1.0.2.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\ujac-1.2.1.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\velocity-dep-1.5.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\vldocking-2.1.4.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\xercesImpl-2.10.0.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\xml-apis-1.4.01.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\xmlbeans-2.4.0.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\libs\xpp3-1.1.4c.jar
401.RECURSE(JAR)
         FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\scort\mi\scortterminalconnector.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\scort\mi\scortutilities.jar
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\scort\mi\scortuts.jar
410.PATH
        PATH    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\properties\scortruntime
411.PATH
        PATH    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\properties\scortterminal
412.PATH
        PATH    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\runtime\properties\dtd\smartpub
420.PATH
        PATH    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\template\sp\jspProducer
500.FILE
        FILE    C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT\eslic.zip
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Target class ...... com.scort.es.framework.EnterpriseStudio
 Target params ..... [-PATH] [C:\ProgramFiles\SCORT\ES-5.5.5-SNASPSHOT]
 Classpath items ... 115
-------------------------------------------------------------
[07:22:04 03/14/23, trace] WELCOME to ENTERPRISE STUDIO v5.5.5
[07:22:04 03/14/23, trace] SYSTEM> specification.version=[11] version=[11.0.2] vendor=[Oracle Corporation] vm.name=[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM] vm.version=[11.0.2+9-LTS] runtime.name=[Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment] runtime.version=[11.0.2+9-LTS] class.version=[55.0]
[07:22:18 03/14/23, notice] Opening editor [#3] for resource "C:\MXW\Clients\SOCIS\examples\ExampleProject\Project.es_prj\Res.es_res\Tutorials AO\Tutorial_SCF.es3270" in project "C:\MXW\Clients\SOCIS\examples\ExampleProject"
[07:22:18 03/14/23, notice] Initialising database for project "ExampleProject".
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/SQLException
        at com.scort.es.persistentstorage.PersistentLocalObject.<clinit>(PersistentLocalObject.java:193)
        at com.scort.es.editor.terminals.repository.TerminalRepStorage.<clinit>(TerminalRepStorage.java:155)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
        at com.scort.es.project.EsProject.loadESPersistentResource(EsProject.java:261)
        at com.scort.es.project.EsProject.initDatabase(EsProject.java:228)
        at com.scort.es.project.EsProject.createNewPersistentStorageSession(EsProject.java:166)
        at com.scort.es.project.EsProject.createPersistentStorageSession(EsProject.java:130)
        at com.scort.es.editor.terminals.RepositoryManager.createTerminalStorage(RepositoryManager.java:117)
        at com.scort.es.editor.terminals.RepositoryManager.setTerminalInits(RepositoryManager.java:391)
        at com.scort.es.editor.terminals.RepositoryManager.setTerminalXML(RepositoryManager.java:357)
        at com.scort.es.editor.terminals.Editor.setup(Editor.java:512)
        at com.scort.es.editor.terminals.Editor.setDeskTop(Editor.java:214)
        at com.scort.es.framework.BeanManager.registerBean(BeanManager.java:483)
        at com.scort.es.framework.TabbedBeanViewer.addTab(TabbedBeanViewer.java:166)
        at com.scort.es.framework.TabbedBeanViewer.addBean(TabbedBeanViewer.java:132)
        at com.scort.es.framework.Framework$3$1.run(Framework.java:1808)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.SQLException
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at java.base/java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:899)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 33 more
[07:22:21 03/14/23, notice] [#3] -- Closed database key <?> (1 ms).
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: TabInfo index is out of bounds.
        at com.scort.es.swing.xtabbedpane.XTabbedPane.removeTabAt(XTabbedPane.java:898)
        at com.scort.es.framework.TabbedBeanViewer.removeBeanAt(TabbedBeanViewer.java:106)
        at com.scort.es.framework.BeanManager.closeBeanAt(BeanManager.java:349)
        at com.scort.es.framework.BeanPanel.closeAllBeans(BeanPanel.java:247)
        at com.scort.es.framework.Framework.closeFramework(Framework.java:683)
        at com.scort.es.framework.Framework$2.windowClosing(Framework.java:595)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.windowClosing(AWTEventMulticaster.java:358)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.windowClosing(AWTEventMulticaster.java:357)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Window.java:2078)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.processWindowEvent(JFrame.java:298)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2037)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Terminer le programme de commandes (O/N) ? o
```

No CNFE since the java.sql module is known from the JVM

Comment: can you install a second jvm for jdk 1.8?

Comment: What do you mean by "installing a second jvm for jdk 1.8"?

Comment: install multiple jdks and define env variables JAVA_HOME='/home/jdk1.8.0_45'
JAVA_7='/home/jdk1.7.0_60'
JAVA_6='/home/jdk1.6.0_34' and run your app with the desired one.

Comment: That does not solve the issue. Our customer wants to use the Java 11 only.

Comment: r u using intelliJ ? if so  please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52981800/getting-noclassfoundexception-java-sql-sqlexception-in-intellij-idea-for-jdk-1